# Windows: How do I set the dimensions for a command window launched by dropping files?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I'm running Windows 7 here.

I have a batch file that takes a list of files as arguments. I've made a shortcut to that program and put it on the desktop. Getting properties on that shortcut lets me change the window dimensions, and when I double-click it, it starts with the dimensions I asked for. Great!

However! When I start it by dragging some files from Explorer and dropping them on the icon (which is how I want to use it), it starts as an 80x25 window. Boo!

Is there a way to make my program start with a big window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have a batch script, the easiest way is simply changing the commandline dimensions inside the batch script itself.

The command to change them is as follows:

```
mode con cols=200 lines=50
```

You can use this also to make the window very small, but there's a minimum. Go lower and the command is simply ignored, giving the following error: `The screen cannot be set to the number of lines and columns specified.`

The minimum amount of lines is 1, columns is 15.

Alternatively, you can also just type the numbers:

```
mode 200,50
```

Comment: Wow, somehow I had never plumbed these batch file depths. Thanks!